# Show that any line $L$ with same slope $K$ is of the form $M + \alpha$

Tags: vector-spaces

> Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $M$ be the line through the origin with slope $k$. Let $M$ be a subspace of $V$. Show that any other line $L$ with the same slope $k$ is of the form $M + \alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

I am not sure what the question is asking, "of the form $M + \alpha$ for some $\alpha$". What does the question want me to do exactly?

Comment: The question asks the following: given some such line $L$, show that there is some $\alpha \in \Bbb R^2$ such that for any $p\in L$ we can write $p = m + \alpha$ for some $m\in M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $M = \{ (x,y):\, y=kx\} = \{ x(1,k):\ x\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Then, any other line with the same slope is in the form 
$$L=\{(x,y):\, y=kx+b\} = \{ (0,b)+x(1,k):\, x\in \mathbb{R}\} = (0,b) + M$$ for some $b\neq 0$. Pick $\alpha := (0,b)$.

In general, so you're not more confused, given a vector space $\textsf{V}$, a vector $v\in \textsf{V}$ and a vector subspace $\textsf{W}$ of $\textsf{V}$, we can define $$v+\textsf{W}$$ 
(yes, the sum of a vector with a whole subspace) to be the set 
$$\{v+w:\, w\in \textsf{W}\}$$

Comment: is the last part $\{v + w : w \in W\}$ read as "for all w in W" or "for a w in W$?

Comment: The most correct interpretation would be the second : $x\in v+\textsf{W}$ if and only if $x=v+w$ for SOME $w\in \textsf{W}$